# Can Terraform be used with AWS autoscale groups to deploy the first member, wait, then deploy the rest as needed?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Not a Terraform expert here,

Is there a way to have Terraform create a node in an empty AWS Autoscale Group, wait, then create all other nodes as quickly as possible with no wait?

The situation is I have an application that uses a shared directory to store common files and is set up with a primary/secondary architecture. The only difference between primary and secondary is primary will create the required files and binaries where as all secondaries consume them. Currently the application cluster is falling down because it tries to create the entire Autoscale Group in one go, creating a race condition where each node thinks it is a primary.

Comment: Does that mean the primary is exactly the same afterwards? What happens if the primary fails and is replaced later? Is the application one you have built or a third party where you are unable to change this behaviour? Where are the common files stored? S3? EFS? Somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your single autoscaling group with two autoscaling groups, one for the primary server and the other for the secondary servers. Use a `depends_on` block in the second group to make it dependent on the first. With this, the second group will not start until after the first group has successfully started. You may also need to use a lifecycle hook so that the primary server can signal to Autoscaling (and then Terraform) that it has started up and completed creating those shared resources.

Comment: There is some complications here in that post deploy there shouldn't be any dependencies on which server comes up first but there is also a hard limit on how many servers the application can have, but this definitely gets close to what I was looking for and I really appreciate the answer.